# I am not able to send my Json file to the Json server in vue

Tags: json, vue.js

[image: this is the output in which object "user" is not visible]

```json
{
  "user":[
    { "name": "Vaibhav" }
  ]
}
```

**this is the code of my json file**

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what is actually happening here but we will probably need far more details/explanations than just this.

Comment: you're probably not sending JSON